# Why is the capacitance calculated with small-signal variables the same as the capacitance from the basic steady-state formula?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, definition, capacitance

As an electrical engineering student I am currently working at a capacitance model for transistors. To verify my model I use Sentaurus TCAD to simulate my device and create capacitance data. I struggle to interpret the generated data, because I feel like I don't understand the definition of capacitances in general. Also looking at [What is capacitance, in general?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227063/what-is-capacitance-in-general) did not help. A big part of my confusion lies in the different capacitance formula.
TCAD calculates the capacitance values, like explained in [What is capacitance, in general?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227063/what-is-capacitance-in-general), by setting a DC operating point and then superimposing small signal excitation voltages on top, so that the capacitance values can be extracted from the admittance like this:
$$
\frac{\delta i_{i}}{\delta v_{j}} = y_{ij} = a_{ij} + i\omega C_{ij}\quad \Rightarrow \quad C_{ij}=\frac{Im(y_{ij})}{\omega}=\frac{Im(y_{ij})}{2\pi\nu}
$$
$\nu$ being the excitation frequency*
In general (steady-state, DC) capacitances are defined like this: $ C=\frac QV $
using indices for the electrodes I can rewrite it to: $ C_{ij} = \frac{Q_i}{V_{j}} $ *assuming that electrode i is at ground*.

Now comparing this definition to the one of the small signal (or with phasors) they don't seem to match, because the steady state one describes the relation of charge to voltage, while the other describes the impact of an admittance on the phase difference between a (small signal) current and voltage.
$$
C_{ij}=\frac {Q_i}{V_j} =\frac{dQ_i}{dV_j}\cdot \frac{dt}{dt}= I_i\frac{dt}{dV_j} = I_i\left(\frac{dV_j}{dt}\right)^{-1} \overset ?{\neq}  \frac 1{2\pi\nu}\cdot Im\left(\frac{d\underline I_i}{dt}\cdot\left(\frac{d\underline V_j}{dt}\right)^{-1}\right) \\= \frac 1{\omega}\cdot Im\left(\frac{d\underline I_i}{d\underline V_j}\right) = \frac {Im\left(\underline Y_{ij}\right)}{\omega} = C_{ij}
$$
*the underlined letters depict phasors*

But still the capacitance is notationalwise the same and should be interchangable. **Why is this possible? Why is not differentiated between small-signal and steady-state capacitance?**

I am very grateful for every answer and input you guys can give me!

Comment: Ideal capacitors are linear devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of capacitance in a linear dielectric is calculated indeed by $\frac{Q}{V}$ but it is a simplification of a situation where the relationship is nonlinear that is abstracted from the more general case of a constitutive *material* relationship between the locally induced polarization and the local electric field $\mathbf P = \mathbf {P(\mathbf{E})}$. (EEs prefer the $D$ over $P$ and write $\mathbf D = \epsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P$, $\mathbf D = \mathbf {D(\mathbf{E})}$.

In the nonlinear case the linear "definition" is not useful except for being as an *operating point* around which one linearizes the same way as you have surely learned of the "gain" of a non-linear amplifier makes no *general* sense unless it is meant to be at a fixed operating point around which you linearize locally.

Comment: So what would be the generalized definition of the capacitance then? Or do I just have to use a more generalized formula like: 
$$
\frac QV=\frac{dD/dv}{\int_A^B Ddl}
$$

Comment: There is no meaningful way to have a "general" capacitance if the $D=D(E)$ relationship is nonlinear just as the amplification or gain of nonlinear amplifier is not meaningful. The function $y=f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$ can be written as Taylor expansion $y(x)=K_1x+K_2x^2+K_3x^3...$ but unless $|x| \ll 1$ you do not have a useful *linear* approximation such as $y \approx K_1x$ and the concept of capacitance is a linear approximation to the function $Q=Q(V)$ or $D=D(E)$.

Comment: Also, in a capacitor, $Q$ is the *surface* integral of the $D$ field over one of the plates, while $V$ is the *line* integral of the $E$ field from one plate to the other; the ratio you wrote is above not the definition of these quantities.

Comment: That means, that the "small signal capacitance" from $C=\frac{Im(\underline Y)}{\omega}$ is the linearized version of a nonlinear (changing) capacitance in that specific operation point. That's why it can be compared to the static or linear version, only for that operation point, right?
Also then the equation should be $\frac{\oint_S Dds}{\int_L Edl}$

Comment: yes, that "C" is the *linearized* capacitance while the ratio of the integrals as you wrote it correctly now represents the static operating ("large signal")point representing the average $V$ or $E$ around which the *tangent* is the linearized ("small signal") capacitance. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

In things like transistor junctions, the geometry changes with applied voltage. Dielectric constants in things like ceramic capacitors are functions of the electric field. In those cases, $Q/V$ is not a constant as a function of voltage. The small-signal capacitance gives you the change in $V$ for a small change in $Q$ (or vice-versa) when they aren't proportional for large changes.

Comment: But isn't the "small signal capacitance" calculated with the admittance, which is the relation for change of current and change of voltage?

Comment: @zraibra You can do it that way, but admittance is frequency-dependent. The small signal capacitance in farads may not be, so it may be more convenient. Depends on the context.